# how to use trivy with jenkins running on docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins, continuous-integration, trivy

My objective is to have Trivy available for my Jenkins pipeline. I have tried so much from installing Trivy on bare metal, to executing into the Jenkins container itself and installing the Trivy and finally installing Trivy as a separate container using docker compose(followed Trivy documentation) nothing works, my pipeline keeps reporting Trivy not found.
Here's my Docker-Compose:

```
version: '3'
services:

  # Jenkins Service
  jenkins:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - JENKINS_HOME=/var/jenkins_home
      - JENKINS_ADMIN_ID=admin
      - JENKINS_ADMIN_PASSWORD=password
      - SERVER_IP=${server_ip}
      - DOCKER_USERNAME=${docker_username}
      - DOCKER_PASSWORD=${docker_password}
      - GITHUB_USERNAME=${github_username}
      - GITHUB_PASSWORD=${github_password}
      - GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN=${github_access_token}
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
      - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker

  # Trivy Service
  trivy:
    image: aquasec/trivy:latest
    volumes:
      - trivy-cache:/root/.cache/
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

  # SonarQube Service
  sonarqube:
    image: sonarqube:latest
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9092:9092"
    volumes:
      - sonarqube_data:/opt/sonarqube/data

volumes:
  # Jenkins Home Volume
  jenkins_home:

  # SonarQube Data Volume
  sonarqube_data:

  # Trivy Cache Volume
  trivy-cache:
```

Any help is appreciated, what I'm I doing wrong?

EDIT: It finally worked using Trivy as a Docker Agent, but is this the best way to do it? Is there a downside to doing this?